# Unexpected size of class in case of virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Can someone please explain about the size of the classes in the case of virtual inheritance involving virtual functions. The code is below:

```
class A
{
public:
    char c;
    virtual void z();
};
class B : public virtual A
{
    double x;
    char a, b;
    int m, n;
public:
    virtual void z();
    virtual int p() { return 0; }
};
```

The size of class B is 48.

Comment: There's nothing to explain. The C++ standard requires no particular size of any class.

Comment: What do you expect the size of the class to be, and why do you think this?

Comment: I was expecting the class B size to be 40 because in the case of non virtual inheritance the size is 32.

Comment: In the case of classes with virtual members or bases, size is _highly_ compiler-dependent.  Your comment suggests compiling with MSVC (expected +8 bytes, got +16 instead); if this is the case, it may surprise you to learn that MSVC actually uses two vtable pointers instead of one, I would suggest [experimenting with class layouts](https://rextester.com/IEPAY44586) a little more, with compiler-specific "display layout" flags enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation.  In you example, there's no reason for sizeof(B) > 32 on a 64-bit machine, other than poor implementation.

In a normal implementation, a 'virtual' class (one with virtual methods or bases) requires a `vtable` pointer for each virtual base (and a minimum of one if there are virtual methods and no virtual bases), and may require additional vtable pointers if there are additional (non-virtual) bases in some situations.  There are also optimizations that can reduce that (particularly link-time class layout).

Comment: Honestly, any implementation that makes `sizeof(B) == 32` is invalid on x64, but should be valid on x86.  `B` contains a `double`, which means `alignof(B)` is at least 8 (and thus, `[x, a, b, m, n]` require 24 bytes after padding).  `A` is `alignof({pointer})`, and thus 8 on x64 or 4 on x86; `A` thus requires 16 bytes by itself, making `sizeof(B)` a minimum of 40 if non-virtual inheritance.  [Barring reordering or padding/alignment change, and provided the implementation uses _roughly_ the same layout rules for virtual inheritance as for standard-layout classes, of course.]

Comment: Since `B` has a vritual base class, it need not follow standard layout, so can use the padding in the embedded A for the 1 byte fields, fitting all of it in just 4 words (32 bytes).  I would consider any implementation that did not do that rather poor.

Comment: I... _think_ that's actually non-compliant, because it would modify the _member-specification_ part of both classes' _class-specifiers_.  The implementation is allowed to change a class' layout when it's used as a base class subobject, yes, but members can only be added in the _member-specification_ (implicitly disallowing members to be moved into a base class subobject).  Compilation silently moving `B` members into `A` would also run the risk of breaking valid polymorphic code, especially code that modifies `B::c` and/or calls `B::z()` through an `A*` or `A&`.

Comment: That said, I can honestly say I have never seen any compiler that actually reorders non-standard-classes' members like this; I even went so far as to test every compiler on Compiler Explorer, using [this hack](https://godbolt.org/z/U02aJE) (apart from RISC-V Clang, due to lacking knowledge of its implementation's library); all of them keep `B`'s members in `B`, and `A`'s padding empty.

Comment: Hmm... upon further research, storing a class member in a prior member's padding is allowed if the prior member is specified to have the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute, so in that case I would say you are entirely correct, provided the elements remain in the specified order.